# JavaScript in C# ASP MVC issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization, castle

We have a web project that takes data from an MS SQL database and uses the Google Visualisation API to display these charts on the web view.

Recently we have added castle windsor so we can configure the application to different users with an XML file. Before we added this, the view worked fine, using the baked in parameters that were needed for this query. For some reason, when we send in the parameters from the XML files (Running with breakpoints shows that the parameters are being passed to the main controller action for the page) the data isn't being returned. here is some of the code for you.

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var csvDataUrl = '@Url.Action("TradeValuesDataCsv", "Dashboard")';
var jsonDataUrl = '@Url.Action("TradeValuesDataJson", "Dashboard")';
 google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ['table', 'corechart', 'gauge'] });
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
 drawCharts();

 $("body").on({
     ajaxStart: function () {
         $(this).addClass("loading");
     },
     ajaxStop: function () {
         $(this).removeClass("loading");
     }
 });

function drawCharts() {
    var queryString = 'platform=' + $('#PlatformDropDownList').val();
    queryString += '&startDate=' + $('#startDatePicker').val();
    queryString += '&endDate=' + $('#endDatePicker').val();
    queryString += '&model=' + $('#ModelDropDownList').val();
    queryString += '&eventType=' + '@Model.EventType';
    queryString += '&parameterName=' + '@Model.ParameterName';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: jsonDataUrl,
            data: queryString,
            statusCode: {
                200: function (r) {
                    drawToolbar(queryString);
                    drawTable(r);
                    drawChart(r);
                },
                400: function (r) {

                },
                500: function (r) {

                }
            }
        });
}
```

Main controller Method for this page:

```
        public ActionResult ActionResultName(EventTypeParameterNameEditModel model)
    {
        var viewModel = new EventTypeParameterNameViewModel(_queryMenuSpecific);
        viewModel.EventType = model.EventType;
        viewModel.ParameterName = model.ParameterName;
        PopulateFilters(viewModel);
        return this.View(viewModel);
    }
```

Retrieve the JSON Data Controller Method:

```
        public ActionResult ActionResultNameJson(EventTypeParameterNameEditModel filters)
    {
        List<CustomDataType> results = this.GetTradeValues(filters);
        return this.Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**EDIT** I have managed to find a solution, even if it is a rather messy one. I have some filters built into the page that allow the user to filter by device and by OS, and these were being populated on the page load with 'undefined'. I didn't spot this first time round with NHProf Running, but this wasn't happening when the page loaded before we configured the input to be from XML. I will add this as an answer and accept it and close the question. Thanks everyone for your attempts to help. Starting to really like this community. Perfect place to find help as a Graduate Developer.

Comment: What's happening on the client-side? "Isn't returned" is a little vague. What status code are you getting (I believe you can check the jqXHR object for that)? Are there javascript errors? Also before we go any further, is your team fond of empty catch statements in try/catch in their JavaScript? If so, hit them in the head with a stick and remove so we can see what's going on.

Comment: There is no error code. I am loading up the web page that this is targeted at, and the page loads fine, Ajax never fires off and the chart or table doesnt appear. There has been no changes to the javascript since we changed the way the values are being passed other than:

Comment: queryString += '&eventType=' + '@Model.EventType';
    queryString += '&parameterName=' + '@Model.ParameterName'; 
These two lines. And it worked fine before we changed the way the data was being passed through the models and controller.

Comment: I've had issues using razor syntax within javascript.  Are you sure that your query string is getting @eventType=whateveryouexpect vs @eventType=@Model.EventType?  Try Console.Log($queryString) before the ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was not in my Javascript. I have some filters in there that allow the user to filter the results my model and operating system and date and what not. These were being automatically populated on page load with 'undefined' which is not an option in the database. I added something to catch that in the call to the query and it seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. I'm not a Razor syntax expert but I think these property references are probably your problem. I suspect razor is going to tend to avoid asserting itself inside strings being used in statements with properties in JS contexts. Or you could try implementing as getter functions which would probably work. Otherwise an @ and a . in a string could easily lead to confusing mixups with email addresses when it's not an obvious method call:

```
queryString += '&eventType=' + '@Model.EventType';
queryString += '&parameterName=' + '@Model.ParameterName';
```

As a general rule in any server to client-side scenario, my advice is to confine JavaScript direct from the back end to JSON objects only. That way you have more granular control over what's going on on both sides of the http request wall and your client-side devs don't have to figure where stuff is getting built if there's a short-term need to quickly modify. In general, don't build behavioral code with other code if you can avoid it.

I couldn't convince my .net MVC boss at first but he slowly came around to the idea on his own months later.

We also store a URL base path along with some other context-shifting params in a standard JSON object that loads on every page so the JS devs can add these things linked JS files rather than have to work with JS in the HTML (I don't recall why but document.location wasn't always going to work).

Lastly, try to keep the JS out of the HTML. Link it. It seems like a pain from a procedural POV but trust me. It makes life much easier when you are juggling 3 major concerns as one ball each rather than all in the same jumbled HTML/template mess.

Comment: Yeah, the JS has been removed from the HTML, it was just developed in there for ease of developer testing before refactoring.